# How to know if user logged in if I use api in yii2

Tags: rest, api, yii2, basic-authentication

I have yii2 as web application. I have an api where I connect using curl. Api has Basic Authentication. I request to api `http://api.example.com:8080//client/auth` using post where I send username and password and it returns token. Should I save this token in database or how I can do this?

Comment: Look here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-authentication.html#authentication API auth implements yii\web\IdentityInterface so after successfully auth you have Yii::$app->user->isGuest() I guess.

Comment: @TomaszKane thanks for response. But       $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
    ]; where I can define host, username and password?

Comment: provide more/full info what you're trying to do? You ask two questions, one in title one in content :-) In example: I use "Query parameter" (access-token) to get access to my REST API in Yii2. My API client store username, password and token in database; user auth (in api client) is by username/email and password. Then api client communicate with api by access-token.

Comment: No, I request to api which is in another host. I send at header Basic Auth. Actually it was already solved. I find that user in my database and login. If I do not find, then I create user in database and after that login and after that I get Yii::$app->user->isGuest. Thanks.